# How to get all tabs except Admin tab in DotNetNuke?

Tags: asp.net, c#-2.0

```
DotNetNuke.Common.Globals.GetPortalTabs(portalID, false, true, false, true, true) this function
```

Here this function returns all Tab list .... But i don't want Admin tab
..so Please help me..

Answer (score 1):

How old is your DNN? `DotNetNuke.Common.Globals.GetPortalTabs` has been replaced since DNN 5.0.

But here is a code snippet to get you started.

```
//get all the tabs in the current portal
List<DotNetNuke.Entities.Tabs.TabInfo> portalTabs = TabController.GetPortalTabs(PortalId, 0, true, false);

//loop all the tabs
foreach (TabInfo tabInfo in portalTabs)
{
    //get the TabPermission for the current tab and cast from Collection to List<TabPermissionInfo>
    List<DotNetNuke.Security.Permissions.TabPermissionInfo> tabPermissionInfo = DotNetNuke.Security.Permissions.TabPermissionController.GetTabPermissions(tabInfo.TabID, PortalId).Cast<DotNetNuke.Security.Permissions.TabPermissionInfo>().ToList();

    //filter out all the TabPermission with administrator using Linq
    List<TabPermissionInfo> tabPermissionInfoFiltered = tabPermissionInfo.Where(x => x.RoleName != "Administrators").ToList();

    //loop all the permissionInfo objects with administrator filtered out
    foreach (TabPermissionInfo permissionInfo in tabPermissionInfoFiltered)
    {
        Label1.Text += tabInfo.TabName + " - " + permissionInfo.RoleName + "<br>"; 
    }
}
```